# Recuperar valor da variavel de ambiente PATH no Linux usando Java

Tags: java, linux, path, variáveis-de-ambiente, variáveis

Não encontrei um tópico bom sobre esse assunto e decidi criar essa pergunta, para aqueles que estiverem passando por esse problema. Ao utilizar `System.getenv("PATH")` não é listado todos os valores dessa variável de ambiente. 
Pontos testados:

- Executar no terminal do linux o comando `echo $PATH` lista corretamente todos os caminhos configurados.
- Desligar a máquina não funciona
- `ProcessEnvironment.environment()` retorna a mesma coisa que o primeiro código

Estou usando esse código:

```
String[] cmd = ['echo', '$PATH']
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

BufferedReader retorno = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))
retorno.readLines()
```

Teoricamente deveria retornar o mesmo valor que no terminal, porém além de não identificar alguns programas como o 'help', ao utilizar o `echo $PATH` o retorno é um array de size 1 com o valor $PATH em string.

Alguém com uma solução interessante para esse problema?

Comment: Já tentou algo como `String variavel = System.getenv("nome_da_variavel");` ?

Comment: Exatamente neste ponto, o comportamento não é o que você espera. `echo $PATH` vai chamar o executável `/bin/echo`, não o builtin da shell, e também vai passar a string `$PATH` para o comando. Ao digitar no terminal `echo $PATH`, quem é invocado é o builtin e, antes de invocar o comando, a própria shell expande a variável e passa para o `echo` o conteúdo de `PATH`. O equivalente do que você tentou fazer no java seria `/bin/echo '$PATH'` (note a aspas-simples que impedem a expansão da variável)

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
```